# Can I give two ranges of number for a plot

Tags: matlab, plot

How I can give two ranges of x for a plot, for a simple example considering `x=0:0.5:50;` and `x=50:10:1000;`

```
y=x.^2
plot(x,y)
```

Comment: I mean one plot not two plots

Comment: One plot with only one x , small x are changing in small steps and large x are changing in big ranges (I gave a simple example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem right, this might be a solution:

```
x = [0:0.5:50, 50:10:1000];
y = x.^2;
plot(x,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the question. Please explain exactly what you need.

If your aim is to concatenate two plots you can simply compute y in the two interval separately.

```
x=0:0.5:50;
y=x.^2;
plot(x,y);
hold on
x=50:10:1000;
y=x.^2;
plot(x,y)
```